# How do I slow down this JQuery effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects, jquery-effects

Code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sync_box').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.toggleClass('opened');

    var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100 ;
    $('.sync_box').stop().animate({height: heights });
  });
});
    </script>
```

Where in this script can I add time to slow it down? i am sure this is obvious but i am new to jquery/js so a bit puzzled.  Please help.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to be puzzled. Just read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Puzzled meaning not sure where to put stuff from time to time like in this case i didn't know where to put time.

Comment: That's why documentation exists. No need to be puzzled when you don't know how to do something. Just look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  Will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.sync_box').stop().animate({ height: heights }, TIME_IN_MS);
```

There buddy.

Be sure to check jquery animate api [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sync_box').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.toggleClass('opened');

    var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100 ;
    $('.sync_box').stop().animate({height: heights },2000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Edited example above. The 2000 is milliseconds.

Reference http://api.jquery.com/animate/